# closing aws root account - what happens to iam users?

Tags: amazon-web-services

sorry for a "newbie" question but i cant seem to find an answer googling. ive also read and followed the help section in the aws console but to no avail.

i created an aws account for my organization a year ago, but im no longer in need of it. our developers use their account to run the service, but mine is the organizations "root" account. to add insult to injury we're on different servers. my account is in frankfurt, the developers is in oregon. the main issue we're having is that my frankfurt server is running up costs that i dont need.

ive terminated all instances, hosts, snapshots etc. but i id like to "kill" the entire region. the only way i see possible is to terminate my user (which i dont care about i never use it) but im worried that would mess up the iam user of my developer.

this is really an issue that stems from me not knowing how aws works when setting stuff up, but it also feel like they over complicate things. so ; how do i terminate my user without messing stuff up for my dev?

thank you!

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlyAi.png)

Comment: You need to contact support. They can help you move accounts to a different organization.

Comment: thank you @jordanm - i did that, but they are slow in answering. figured id ask here as well. as soon as i get a definitive answer back from support ill post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so after getting a hold of aws i finally got an answer.

iam user is its own user so terminating the root user does not remove the iam user. even though i am running the "root" account it doesnt mean that all accounts linked to it or "below" it gets removed, but it can render it useless. it all depends on who is paying for the account. if the iam user has a credit card connected then youre all set to go!

1. at that point you first need to stop and terminate all instances and such running on your server.
2. delete all user groups
3. finally delete your user.